# How to get specific entries from a HashMap in JDOQL?

Tags: java, jdoql

How can I use `JDOQL` to get a specific entry from a `HashMap` from the following structure:

```
class User {
    String username;
    Map<String, String> projects; //project name serves as the key
}

user.setUsername("John");
user.getProjects().add("Test Project", "Content");
```

I now want to look for the user "John" and fetch content (`HasMaph.value`) of the project named "Test Project".

The following will select the `User` itself. Can I rewrite the query so that the specific project content is directly fetched without retrieving the user?

```
Query q = pm.newQuery("SELECT UNIQUE path.to.User WHERE username == :username" AND projects.contains(project)");
User user = (User) q.execute("John", "Test Project");
user.get("Test Project);
```